# How to drag text into list in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have been following tutorial for TicTacToe game https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/development/dotnet-development/using-unity-ui-and-c-to-create-a-tic-tac-toe-game/. My problem begins from Figure 41, where I have to paste Text objects into list in MainController.

[image]
[image]

Should SpaceText be in blue color, to allow it to drag it to list? How to fix this issue? SpaceText can't be dragged into Assets.

Edit, after opening SpaceText in prefab mode and dragging SpaceText into Assets:
[image]

Space.cs:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using TMPro;

public class Space : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Button button;
    public Text button_text;
    private MainController main_controller;

    public void SetControllerReference(MainController control)
    {
        main_controller = control;
    }

    public void SetSpace()
    {
        button_text.text = main_controller.GetSide();
        button.interactable = false;
        main_controller.EndTurn();
    }
}
```

MainController.cs:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using TMPro;

public class MainController : MonoBehaviour
{

    public TextMeshProUGUI[] space_list;
    public GameObject game_over_panel;
    public TextMeshProUGUI game_over_text;
    public GameObject restart_button;
    private string side;
    private int moves;
    
    void Start()
    {
        SetMainControllerReferenceForButtons();
        side = "X";
        game_over_panel.SetActive(false);
        moves = 0;
        restart_button.SetActive(false);
    }

    
    void SetMainControllerReferenceForButtons()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < space_list.Length; i++){
            space_list[i].GetComponentInParent<Space>().SetControllerReference(this);
        }
    }

    public string GetSide()
    {
        return side;
    }

    void ChangeSide()
    {
        if (side == "X")
        {
            side = "O";
        } else {
            side = "X";
        }
    }

    public void EndTurn()
    {
        moves++;
        if (space_list[0].text == side && space_list[1].text == side && space_list[2].text == side)
        {
            GameOver();
        }
        else if (space_list[3].text == side && space_list[4].text == side && space_list[5].text == side)
        {
            GameOver();
        }
        else if (space_list[6].text == side && space_list[7].text == side && space_list[8].text == side)
        {
            GameOver();
        }
        else if (space_list[0].text == side && space_list[3].text == side && space_list[6].text == side)
        {
            GameOver();
        }
        else if (space_list[1].text == side && space_list[4].text == side && space_list[7].text == side)
        {
            GameOver();
        }
        else if (space_list[2].text == side && space_list[5].text == side && space_list[8].text == side)
        {
            GameOver();
        }
        else if (space_list[0].text == side && space_list[4].text == side && space_list[8].text == side)
        {
            GameOver();
        }
        else if (space_list[2].text == side && space_list[4].text == side && space_list[6].text == side)
        {
            GameOver();
        }

        if (moves >= 9)
        {
            game_over_panel.SetActive(true);
            game_over_text.text = "Remis";
            restart_button.SetActive(true);
        }
        ChangeSide();
    }

    void GameOver()
    {
        game_over_panel.SetActive(true);
        game_over_text.text = side + " wygrywa!";
        restart_button.SetActive(true);
        for (int i = 0; i < space_list.Length; i++)
        {
            SetInteractable(false);
        }
    }

    void SetInteractable(bool setting)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < space_list.Length; i++)
        {
            space_list[i].GetComponentInParent<Button>().interactable = setting;
        }
    }

    public void Restart()
    {
        side = "X";
        moves = 0;
        game_over_panel.SetActive(false);
        SetInteractable(true);
        restart_button.SetActive(false);
        for (int i = 0; i < space_list.Length; i++)
        {
            space_list[i].text = "";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If dragging isn't working you can try clicking the circle with the dot in the middle on the right hand side of each element in the list. A window with all possible objects that can go in the field should appear. This might also give a clue why the dragging isn't working.

Comment: I'd like to see code samples. You gave a link to a tutorial, but me, being lazy, can't see the code to analyze it. I want to know what type is list, and what type of objects are those texts. If they are SomeFancyTextComponent:Text and list is just List<Text> then it won't accept them.

Answer (score 2):

The Space_list is a collection of type Text[], which means that you can only drag GameObjects that contain the [Text component](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/script-Text.html) into it.

[image]

So you need to [open the SpaceText prefab](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/EditingInPrefabMode.html) and add the Text component to its root GameObject, then you will be able to drag and drop those SpaceText GameObjects init to the Space_list.

The blue box icon indicates that a GameObject is an instance of a [prefab](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Prefabs.html) asset. What this means in a nutshell is that if you modify the prefab asset, then all instance of that prefab will also be affected by that change.

Comment: how to add the Text component to its root GameObject ?

Comment: I opened SpaceText in Prefab mode and dragged it to Assets and it is now in blue color. Still, I can't drag it to the list and when I click the circle with the dot, there is only "None" there.

Comment: You are almost there! You added a TextMeshPro - Text component instead of a Text component to the GameObject. They are very similar but the TextMeshPro variant is newer and better in some ways. If you change the type of the Space_list variable in your code from Text[] to TextMeshProUGUI[] then things should start working.

Comment: now I dragged it into the place, thanks!. However, when I run the app, now the type of main_controller.GetSide() doesn't match. There is an error "NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object Space.SetSpace() (at Assets/Space.cs:20)

Comment: The issue isn't main_controller.GetSide(), you can assign a string value to both Text.text and TextMeshProUGUI.text just fine. NullReferenceException always means that you've tried to access a member on an object that is missing. You're seeing this because you haven't dragged a Text component to the Button_text field on your Space component. Usually when you see even one blank Object field in the Inspector that's a warning sign that the component probably hasn't been set up properly yet.

Comment: I have been trying to drag a Text component (SpaceText) into Button_text field on my Space component, but it can't be dragged. Should I change something in the code? I click on Space, then Space(Script) and then there is Button_text.

Comment: I think you are once again trying to drag a GameObject with the TextMeshPro - Text component into Text field. This will not work, as they are two different components. It's probably easiest if you change all Text and Text[] fields in your code to TextMeshProUGUI and TextMeshProUGUI[].

Answer (score 0):

SpaceText gameobjects should have [Text](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/script-Text.html) component.